# Merge disk partitions - Win 7, Win 8 & Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, operating-systems, merge

I have three operating systems in my laptop: Windows 7, Windows 8 and Ubuntu.

I installed Windows 8 just to test it (I should have installed into a virtual machine...), but now I want to remove Windows 8 and merge the partition of it with the partition of Windows 7.

Is it possible to do that without formatting the computer?
What tool should I use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your first partition is Windows 7 and the second is Windows 8, you can do this just using tools coming with Windows 7:

1. Boot Windows 7
2. Open the disk management
3. Simply delete the Windows 8 partition
4. Resize the Windows 7 partition to use the now available free space

However, if you have some partition layout where the Windows 7 partition comes *after* your Windows 8 partition or if they are not "neighbors" at all (e.g. first Windows 7, then Ubuntu, then Windows 8), you would have to boot a linux-based live system like [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) or [parted magic](http://partedmagic.com/) to move/delete/resize partitions. **Be careful though to not mess up your system.**

Comment: They just need to be "neighbors"? Should I format the Windows 8 partitions before add it to windows 7 partition?

Comment: If both partitions are located next to each other and the Windows 7 partition comes first, its file system can be easily expanded to use the free space from the deleted second partition. Just follow the 4 steps and you should be done - formatting is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [Gnome Partition Editor](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/).

It can perform actions with partitions such as:

- create or delete
- resize or move
- check
- label
- set new UUID
- copy and paste

Manipulate file systems such as:

- btrfs
- ext2 / ext3 / ext4
- fat16 / fat32
- hfs / hfs+
- linux-swap
- nilfs2
- ntfs
- reiserfs / reiser4
- ufs
- xfs

And many more features

Comment: Isn't a problem if the two partitions have operating systems? This tool can do that without problem?

Comment: Gnome Partition Editor is a bootable CD.  By booting off the CD, you have complete access to all the disks and partitions, regardless of what is on them.

Answer (score 0):

Simply delete the Windows 8 partition, set the Windows 7 partition to active, and reboot.

Some great programs that can easily do this for you

[gParted live cd](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php)

[Norton Ghost](http://us.norton.com/ghost/)

[Acronis Disk Director](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/diskdirector/)